# psql and pg_dump at same paths return different version information in Rakefile when run from IntelliJ IDea

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql, intellij-idea, rubymine

In IDea 11.1.3 Build-IU#117.798 and trying to use its Ruby plugin to run specs in a project that uses Rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0].

I think it is related to having a homebrew version of postgres installed on OS X Lion Server (10.7.5) which I have on my path before the OS X server version of pg.

In Terminal.app:

```
$ whereis pg_dump
/usr/bin/pg_dump
$ pg_dump -V
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.1.3
$ psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.3
contains support for command-line editing
$ /path/to/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -e 'puts "#{`pg_dump -V`}"'
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.1.3
$ /path/to/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -e 'puts "#{`psql -V`}"'
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.3
contains support for command-line editing
```

If I add this to my Rakefile:

```
raise "whereis pg_dump = #{`whereis pg_dump`}, pg_dump -V = #{`pg_dump -V`}, psql -V = #{`psql -V`}"
```

In IDea, when I do Run -> Debug -> spec this is what is shown in the console:

```
/path/to/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /path/to/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@some_project/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/bin/rdebug-ide --port 51515 -- /path/to/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake spec
Testing started at 10:59 AM ...
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:51515
rake aborted!
whereis pg_dump = /usr/bin/pg_dump
, pg_dump -V = pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.0.5
, psql -V = psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.5

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Process finished with exit code 137
```

Any idea why it would be getting a different version for binaries at the same path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is different in RubyMine and in Terminal. To make it the same run RubyMine from Terminal:

```
open -a /Applications/RubyMine.app/
```

Another option is to specify `PATH` in RubyMine Run/Debug configuration.

Related topics:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51677
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57385/17551
- http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work for me. In IDea, `open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 11.app/` fixes it, or Run -> Edit Configurations -> (Rake/spec) and for brew postgres to work you click on ... right of Environment variables, click the + and add PATH with value `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH`, click Ok, then click Apply and Ok. Thanks a lot!